# C# FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, filenotfoundexception

So, I have a C# application with a GUI that's been written in XAML. My application was running and displaying correctly a moment ago, however, after making some minor changes to one of the GUI elements in the XAML (literally just resizing and moving a button), I built my code again, but now when trying to run it, I get and error message that says:

> FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code

The error is highlighting the line:

```
WebKit.WebKitBrowser browser = new WebKit.Browser();
```

in my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file (`MainWindow.xaml` being the GUI source file where I repositioned one of the GUI elements).

I have come across this error before, and fixed it by going to Project --> Add Reference, and checking the tick box for 'WindowsFormsIntegration'... However, I have double checked this, and it is still selected.

I have looked in my folder structure, and can see that the `WebKit.Interop.dll` file is present in both my Debug and Release folders...

I have also tried undoing the changes I made to the GUI, rebuilding, and running the code again, but I get the same error.

Anyone have any ideas why this is? Have I accidentally clicked/ pressed something I shouldn't have? How can I resolve this issue?

**Edit**

When I click 'View Detail...' on the `FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code` message that's displayed, the `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` says:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'WebKit.Interop, Version=533.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b967213f6d29a3be' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"WebKit.Interop, Version=533.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b967213f6d29a3be"}

The `InnerException` has value:

> null

The `FileName` is:

> WebKit.Interop, Version=533.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b967213f6d29a3be

The `FusionLog` is:

> === Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: DisplayName = WebKit.Interop, Version=533.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b967213f6d29a3be
>    (Fully-specified)
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>
> ## Calling assembly : WebKitBrowser, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b967213f6d29a3be.
>
> LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: C:...\bin\Debug\WpfApplication1.vshost.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file: 
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: WebKit.Interop, Version=533.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b967213f6d29a3be
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/WebKit.Interop.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/WebKit.Interop/WebKit.Interop.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/WebKit.Interop.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/.../bin/Debug/WebKit.Interop/WebKit.Interop.EXE.

When I look in the folder location specified by the `FusionLog`, I can see the `WpfApplication1.vshost.exe` file it's looking for... (there are `WpfApplication1.vshost` Application Manifest, `WpfApplication1.vshost` Application, `WpfApplication1.vshost.exe` XML Configuration & `WpfApplication1.vshost.exe.manifest` MANIFEST files all in that location... (and a few others: `.exe`, `.exe.manifest` `Source Browser Database`, etc)

**Edit**

The code where this exception is occurring is just above the constructor for my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` class, i.e. where I am declaring the global variables for that class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebKit;
using System.Collections;

namespace Agent
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ...
        System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
        WebKit.WebKitBrowser browser = new WebKit.WebKitBrowser();

        ...
    }
}
```

The exception is being thrown on the line:

```
WebKit.WebKitBrowser browser = new WebKit.WebKitBrowser();
```

and says that it

> Could not load the file or assembly WebKit.Interop, Version 533.0.0.0 ...

Comment: Add handler for AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException and post full stacktrace and InnerException if any

Comment: Don't know why but can't edit comment on Android App . Look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sounds like normal fun with visual studio - do a full clean, close visual studio, and reopen.   Sad, but these kind of issues tend to be fixed after this.

Comment: Yeah, first thing I tried was a clean/ rebuild... Also tried cleaning, then closing & reopening, and running it again, but I'm getting the same problem...

Comment: The thing is @Peuczyński, I haven't actually changed any of the C# source code at all since it last built and ran successfully... just moved and resized one element of the GUI in the `.xaml` file...

Comment: I feel for you but it is irrelevant, show us StackTrace, InnerException, anything that could help us help you. And I assume that you use git (or sth else), if yes - try checkouting the version before the changes in the UI and see if the changes are definately the cause of the problem. Do not make post hoc ergo propter hoc please

Comment: I have added the information that the 'View Detail' dialog box gives about the exception- if there's anything I've not included that would be useful, please let me know.

Comment: Is there anything I need to change/ add in the configuration, such as a Reference Path?

Comment: So now you can see that the GUI change was not the problem as I would have guessed. Check your project configuration and make sure you know where the build folder is. Some time ago in one of my projects somebody switched configuration by accident and I thought that I was runing from ..\Build\Debug\App but in fact I was running it form default \bin\Debug. My guess is your problem is similar. Also just add MessageBox displaying current directory and see if it matches. After that you can manually resolve missing dependency (I can show you later). It may also be project config problem.

Comment: The build folder (Output path in the project properties) is the folder I am expecting- and the same one I have been using since I started working on this project, i.e. `bin\Debug`, which is where all of the files I mentioned in my OP are located... What should I check in the configuration? It is currently configured to build in Debug, on 'Any CPU'...

Comment: Can you upload the code somewhere? It may be anything now. Now my guess would be the missing file is actually dependency of your dependency.

Comment: I've updated my OP to show the code where the exception is occurring.

Comment: No more ideas, sorry

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: most likely causes are that either the file (webkit.interop.dll) is not there - did you look? Or that the dll is 32 bit and you compiled 64 bit or vice versa. Click off 'favor 32 bit', choose right build for the dll

Comment: It seems that was the problem- I had manually copied it to that folder, but must have accidentally done a 'rebuild' at some point, and the compiler must have removed that dll when cleaning the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I had done a 'rebuild', rather than just building my code again, and the compiler had removed the `webkit.interop.dll` file from my build folder. After manually copying `webkit.interop.dll` over from the release build folder to the debug build folder again, this resolved the problem.